# Struts2 Multiple Landing Page Result

Tags: java, struts2, action

So in my struts2 project I have multiple types of users and each type has it's own "landing page". In each user's session Map I store the user type and in many of the actions afterwards I request the type and return it in order to return to the users landing page.
In essence I have a bunch of actions in my struts.xml that look something like this

```
<action name="login" method="execute"
        class="user.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="1">User1.jsp</result>
        <result name="2">User2.jsp</result>
        <result name="3">User3.jsp</result>
    </action>

<action name="anotherAction" method="execute"
        class="user.action.AnotherAction">
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="1">User1.jsp</result>
        <result name="2">User2.jsp</result>
        <result name="3">User3.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

This "landing page" is central to the use of the webpage and the user will often return to it.

My question is, is there a way to simply direct the user to their individual landing page without listing each result as such? I feel like there should be a way to simplify this but am having a difficult time imagining it.

Comment: How the user is related to it's page? How did you choose it in the code?

Comment: Something like global results? http://struts.apache.org/docs/result-configuration.html#ResultConfiguration-GlobalResults.